# Creating a Smooth Line in 3D R

Tags: r, 3d, smoothing, loess

I have a set of 3-dimensional points, like the sample data below. I would like to create a smooth line from it. There's information out there about to smooth a 2D surface in 3D space but how would I smooth a 1D line in 3D space?

```
Z = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
X = rnorm(length(Z), mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
Y = 2 * Z ^ 2 + rnorm(length(Z), mean = 0, sd = 0.1)

data = data.frame(X = X, Y = Y, Z= Z)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want the result to look like.  Do you want a smooth line that passes through those points, or do you want a line that smooths away the random noise (i.e. something like `(0, 2*Z^2, Z)` for `Z` going from 0 to 1 )?  Do you always know that `X` and `Y` should be functions of `Z`?

Comment: Sorry, a line that smooths away the random noise. `X` and `Y` will always be functions of `Z` (I'm looking at spatial points of a tree trunk and trying to get an approximate curve of the trunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of multivariate regression.  If you happen to know that the relationship with `Z` should be quadratic, you can do

```
fit <- lm(cbind(X, Y) ~ poly(Z, 2))
```

But I'm assuming you don't know that, and want some kind of general smoother.  I don't think `loess`, `lowess`, or `gam` handle multivariate regression, but you can use natural splines in `lm`:

```
library(splines)
fit <- lm(cbind(X, Y) ~ ns(Z, df = 4))
```

The fitted values will be returned in a two-column matrix by `predict(fit)`.
To plot the result, you can use `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(X, Y, Z, col = "red")
lines3d(cbind(predict(fit), Z))
```

[image: screenshot]